# Why did Gödel think the Viennese Academy of Sciences was founded earlier?

Tags: science, early-modern, renaissance, mathematics, enlightenment

Mathematician Karl Menger, a colleague of famous mathematician Kurt Gödel, says [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=BKIyBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA223&dq=godel+viennese+academy&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3pbv67KD4AhUxg4kEHcvuBSUQ6AF6BAgHEAM) on pages 222-223 of his book “Reminiscences of the Vienna Circle and the Mathematical Colloquium“:

> Meanwhile, Gödel was more and more preoccupied with Leibniz. He was now completely convinced that important writings of this philosopher had not only failed to be published, but were destroyed in manuscript. Once I said to him teasingly, "You have a vicarious persecution complex on Leibniz' behalf." **Soon afterwards he said, "There is something I have wanted to ask you for quite a while. When was the Viennese (now Austrian) Academy of Sciences founded?" I immediately suspected what Gödel was after. It is a historical fact that Leibniz negotiated for a time with the Emperor and his government about the founding of an Academy in Vienna, but that the negotiations came to nothing. My answer to Gödel’s question was, "In the year 1846, under the predecessor of Emperor Franz Josef." Gödel was visibly disappointed and replied: "You are saying what everyone else says.""What kind of answer did you expect from me?"I asked. "At the time of Leibniz, of course'"** he said. "In the Proceedings of the Viennese Academy, there appeared important writings of Leibniz which, however, were destroyed. "I reminded him of the stranded negotiations and asked him: "How could the founding of the Academy be kept secret for centuries? How could its Proceedings disappear without a trace? Who had an interest in destroying Leibniz' writings?" "Naturally those people who do not want man to become more intelligent," he replied. Since it was unclear to me whom he suspected, I asked after groping for a response. "Don't you think that they would sooner have destroyed Voltaire's writings?" Gödel’s astonishing answer was: "Who ever became more intelligent by reading the writings of Voltaire?" Unfortunately at that moment someone stepped into the room and the conversation was never concluded.

It’s well known that Gödel had a conspiracy theory that Gottfried Leibniz’s Characteristica Universalis, a universal formal language, had been suppressed.  But my question is, on what basis did Gödel believe that the [Viennese Academy of Sciences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austrian_Academy_of_Sciences) was founded earlier than its official founding date of 1846?

And is there any evidence that he was right in his belief?

Comment: Did Menger provide a date for this exchange?

Comment: @Spencer My university library has Menger's book. Unfortunately, the section this is excerpted from merely gives vague time-description and doesn't say anything specific like "in the 1950s." Plus, this chapter jumps backwards and forwards in time, so you can't really figure it out from the context.

Comment: @Spencer I believe it was in the Spring of 1939, when Gödel was at Notre Dame.